# Why isn't local bootstrap.css seen?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In an Angular 4 project, when I reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
```

in index.html, all is well. If I comment out the above, I no longer have styling. My paths look like this:

```
- node_modules
- e2e
- src
-- lib
-- main.ts
---- bootstrap
------ dist
-------- css
- .angular-cli.json
```

I do have this entry in .angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],
```

Why doesn't the above work? boostrap.css is in the referenced folder. index.html is in the root of the `src` folder.

Comment: Is folder `lib` is at the same level as the `.angular-cli.json` file? What does your folder structure look like? Try `"../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`

Comment: Do you really have a `css` folder within `dist`? I don't see it in the structure

Comment: I've updated the tree graph to reflect that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you folder structure is as follows:

```
- node_modules
- e2e
- src
- .angular-cli.json
-- main.ts
-- lib
---- bootstrap
------ dist
-------- css
---------- bootstrap.css
```

Then the entry within `angular-cli.json` needs to be with a prefix of `../` or target the `lib` folder directly as it's the same level as `main.ts`:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../src/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```

or

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```

The paths need to be relative to the `main.ts` entry point/file.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Based on the updated tree structure in the OP, I've tried this without success: `./src/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. `../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` also does not work.

Comment: I checked your project and that does seem to work. But if I put an invalid path to bootstrap.css, I don't see any effect. How is that even possible? It should break the styling right?

Comment: If you clone the sample project and put an invalid path, `@angular/cli` during a command like `ng serve` will throw errors and prevent compilation.

Comment: If I change the path in `.angular-cli.json` to `"../foobar/src/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`, it gives an error like "ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./foobar/src/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Module not found: Error: Can't resolve..."

Comment: ah - I see that now and can replicate the error on my site. I'm not sure what to do. The path is correct because the site builds. Yet, the only way I can get the styling to work is to use the CDN bootstrap.css. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: Perhaps try using an npm module of Bootstrap. Run `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save` then update the path in `"styles"` to be `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. That way you can also manage the version in the `package.json` file. If you are still not seeing it, you may need to share some HTML in case Bootstrap isn't being used effectively.

Comment: I did the npm install and update the styles path. It built fine but the visual styling is still not there. I'll see if I can share some HTML since this is a very localized issue. Thanks!